# conditional statements within the playbook to copy the file to two different locations based on the variables passed in the command

Tags: ansible

I want to copy the file to a location (there a two different locations) based on the variable passed in the command line arguments.
I'm using copy module to do the copy.

```
  - name: Copy the file
    copy:
       src: /mydocuments/folder1/file.txt
       dest: /mypictures/folder1
       owner: myuser
       group: mygroup
       mode: 0755
       remote_src: true
```

basically, when the variable passed in the command is "mypictures" it should copy the file.txt to the dest:/mypictures/folder1 and if the variable is "myfolder" it should copy to dest:/myfolder1/notes

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the variable passed in is `myvar`, set up the destination like so:

```
- name: set array
  set_fact:
    dest:
      myfolder: /myfolder1/notes
      mypictures: /mypictures/folder1

- name: Copy the file
  copy:
    src: /mydocuments/folder1/file.txt
    dest: "{{ dest[myvar] }}"
    owner: myuser
   group: mygroup
   mode: 0755
   remote_src: true
```

Comment: Thank you Jack. I will give it a try.